# User deleted notification or callback from Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an application that requires some records to exist in a database for registered users. I've created a custom Azure AD B2C policy that pushes this user information to the database through REST API claims exchange. This also allows the records to be updated when the profile is edited.

Now I'd like to remove records for users that are deleted from the B2C tenant.

Is there any way to receive a notification of some sort when users are deleted?

Comment: How do you delete the user from the B2C directory in the first place? I don't remember seeing any User Flow to do that... Does the user do it themselves, or does your web app does it through Azure Graph API calls?

Comment: Users can be deleted using graph API or the portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [differential query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-differential-query). You will need to use a batch service (using client credentials flow to get an access token) that periodically runs the query to get the deleted users.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.